# Clickable Link to Header

Tags: media, navigation, theming

I'd like to have a header with PNG files, that are clickable.

I am using Drupal 7 and Omega Theme.

In the Omega default.css, I've added the following:

```
.branding-data {

    height: 250px;
    background-image: url('../images/slideheader1-object1441486291.png'),url('../images/slideheader1-object1068949429.png'),url('../images/slideheader1-object1159417376.png'),  url('../images/slideheader1.jpg');
        background-size: 100% 23.2%,49.55% 99.6%,39.51% 100%,  100%;
        background-position: 0px 192px,292px 4px,505px 0px,  0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

It adds the images to my header. One of these should be a link to another page.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to display clickable images in header of site?

Answer (score 0):

answer found.

I've resolved this by adding new Blocks instead of background images:

```
<p><a href="../link to somewhere"><img alt="" src="http://www.imagelocation/image.png" style="height:150px; line-height:1.538em; width:110px"></a></p>
```

Thereby adding Images, that are links to my header.

In the CSS files i then adjusted the position and opacity.

Greets,
Chris